# Get value from a different element when creating an event handler

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I have a series of HIDDEN contactID elements listed on a page and I've assigned an event handler to a nearby anchor (clicking the anchor pops up the contact's profile). I want to be able to pass in the value of the HIDDEN element when creating the event handler (the anchor might not be right next to the HIDDEN element, so I don't want to traverse the DOM).

```
<input type="hidden" name="first-contact" id="first-contact" value="1" />
<.. code ..>
<a href="#" class="contact-viewer">View contact</a>

<input type="hidden" name="second-contact" id="second-contact" value="4" />
<.. code ..>
<a href="#" class="contact-viewer">View contact</a>
```

The way I'm currently doing it is to put the HIDDEN element's ID tag in the anchor's REL attribute and grabbing the REL value when running my event.

```
<a href="#" class="contact-viewer" rel="second-contact">View contact</a>
```

This works nicely, but it just doesn't feel right (I feel like using REL is a hack). Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual strategy here would be to give the link an *href* attribute so that if scripting isn't available or fails on the client, the server can fulfil the request. In that case, the required value can be in the *href* attribute.

If scripting is available, get the value from the *href*, cancel naviation and complete the request using XHR or whatever.

If you don't want to use the link as a link, then use a button. Links infer navigation to another page, buttons infer a process that will stay on the same page.

Answer (score 1):

The ideal approach is to specify the relationship through grouping HTML elements together (wrapping in a `<div>` for example), and then use parent/child DOM traversal.

However, if this can't be done, then the approach you're taking is a good one. The only problem as you've mentioned is the use of the `rel` attribute. With HTML5, you are allowed use `data-` attributes for this purpose:

```
<a href="#" class="contact-viewer" data-contact="first-contact">View contact</a>
```

You can retrieve that value in your event handler with:

```
el.getAttribute('data-contact');
```

See more information about custom data attributes [here](http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/).

Comment: Ah yes, I didn't think of wrapping them in `DIV` groups. Will def check out data- as well. Thanks!